# download untrusted certifcate in Chrome (Mac)

Tags: macos, download, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have this website which contains an untrusted certificate (self signed). Now I want to download this certificate. But, for example, in Chrome, you only can 'Proceed' or go back (no download option). I'm on a Mac, so I've checked the Keychain access tool but it contains a lot. First of all I don't know if the cert is supposed to be in here, and second, I actually don't know how it looks like. For example, the url is https://example.com:8181/myApp
Any suggestions how to find the cert ?

UPDATE: I just noticed that in Chrome you can click on the right of the url on the lock icon. It show some cert info, but still no option to download :(

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the way to go is using the lock-icon next to the url. You can drag the certificate icon to, for example, you desktop. It is explain [here](http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/).

Answer (score 11):

```
openssl s_client -connect {HOSTNAME}:{PORT} </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mycertfile.pem
```

[...explained here.](https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. I needed this fix to get around my company's self-signed intranet sites. Thanks!