# How can I make Alamofire perform HTTPS request, using a certificate self-signed by an Unknown CA?

Tags: swift, ssl-certificate, alamofire

I have a webserver that is using a self-signed certificate and I have created a "truststore" based on its certificate.

I am running into the following error:

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to
> a server that is pretending to be "192.168...." which could put your
> confidential information at risk

Here is some of my implementation:

```
let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "truststore-root", ofType: "cer")
let localCertificate : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert! )!

let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
    certificates : [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate)!],
    validateCertificateChain : true,
    validateHost : false
)

let serverTrustPolicies = [
    "https://192.168.50.31" : serverTrustPolicy
]

return Alamofire.SessionManager(
    configuration: configuration,
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to include your self signed ssl certificate in your apps target.

Note: The certificate must be in a format that iOS can read. You may need to convert your `truststore-root.cer` file to a different format. In some cases this is a trial and error procedure.

Then you can adjust your code to use the convenient `certificates(in:)` function of `ServerTrustPolicy` like this:

```
let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
    certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
    validateCertificateChain: true,
    validateHost: false
)

let serverTrustPolicies = [
    "192.168.50.31": serverTrustPolicy
]

return Alamofire.SessionManager(
    configuration: configuration,
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
)
```

This function will scan your main bundle and return all the included files with one of the following suffixes ".cer", ".CER", ".crt", ".CRT", ".der", ".DER".

**UPDATE**: You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32009703/6791677) answer to download your ssl certificate from the terminal. Then double click it to import it to your Keychain. Finaly you can export your certificate from the Keychain as a .cer file. This has the correct format that iOS can read. Verify that this is the case by manually invoking the `certificates(in:)` function of `ServerTrustPolicy`. It should now return your certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried converting the certificate to der, p12, among others to no avail. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can always completely disable ssl certificate evaluation for this IP, but this is not suggested generally. I can add this workaround to my answer if you interested. Other than that, you should be able to find a correctly formatted certificate file that the `certificates(in:)` function can return.

Comment: Thanks, I was reading the documentation here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176 It seems DNS might be the culprit. `TLS server certificates must present the DNS name of the server in the Subject Alternative Name extension of the certificate. DNS names in the CommonName of a certificate are no longer trusted.`

Comment: @Brandex07 pinning the ssl certificate should theoretically bypass the iOS default trust policy. I have updated my answer to include steps for download your ssl certificate and a way to convert it to the correct format. Try it out.